# Hyper-V Server hvremote.wsf Script - ns lookup for DNS Verification test fails

Tags: domain-name-system, hyper-v

I'm trying to connect my Hyper-V Server to a Windows 8 client for remote management.

I have:

Joined server to WORKGROUP

Enabled Remote Management

Set the server name

Set a static IP

Set the DNS servers to my ISPs DNS Servers (same as default DNS Servers on my Windows 8 remote management client)

Set the correct time zone

Created net user on server  (net user /add admin password)

Added user to special Administrators group on server (hvremote /add:admin)

Granted anonymous dcom access on client using hvremote

However, the "ns lookup for DNS verification" fails on both the client and server with the same error:

Server: my.isps.server.name.net

Address: 111.222.333.1

********* my.isps.server.name.net can't find 192.168.1.3: Non-existent domain

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your ISP DNS servers don't hold DNS records for your internal network. What you need to do is to set up an internal DNS server that your internal hosts will use for DNS name resolution. Once set up you can manually add the relevant host records for your internal hosts or you can configure your internal hosts to dynamically register and update their own DNS records.

Note that DDNS is the default for Windows DNS clients but in order for it to work in a workgroup you need to configure the hosts with your internal DNS suffix and you need to configure your internal DNS zone to allow secure and non-secure updates.

There are other variables that could come into play (such as if you create an AD domain and join these computers to the AD domain) but I've intentionally tried to keep my answer as simple as possible.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the whole point of doing the Workgroup set upset up was to avoid having to create a domain controller and dns server. Is this more like a warning than an error in my case or do I actually need to set up this DNS server you say in order to have remote management of my server?

Comment: If what you're doing requires DNS resolution of the internal hosts then you need a DNS server that will: A. host those internal host records and B. Resolve those internal host records.

Comment: I guess the real question is Does remote management of a server through WORKGROUPS require DNS resolution? Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to connect and manage the servers by name then you need some type of name resolution. DNS is the most reliable method for that.